# Kotlin compiler on android

Tags: android, kotlin, dex, dx, termux

I'm trying to create a `dex` of the huge jar of the [kotlin commandline compiler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html), so I can develop (i.e. compile) kotlin on a phone (in `termux`).

But `dx` runs out of RAM and is "Killed".

So, maybe divide into smaller `dex`s, and run as multidex? (also, close all other apps!)

**Divide into `dex`s**: fully extract the jar to files; separate with parallel directory structures; then apply `dx` to create one `dex` per root.

This worked, and I found `dx` could handle up to 13MB of classes, and I got the total 100MB of classes into 9 `dex`s.

**Specify multiple `dex`s to `dalvikvm`** - just like multiple jars with regular java. e.g.:

```
dalvikvm -cp sepdex_Main.dex:sepdex_Sep.dex sepdex.Main
```

NB: not `/system/bin/dalvikvm`, but `termux`'s version, which fixes up the ld library path.

The next problem is that `kotlinc` uses `dynamicInvoke`, which requires `sdk-level 26` ([Android 8](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html)). I have Android 5.1, so the story ends here (for me).

Comment: Did you manage to do that?

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode No, still don't have an Android 8 dwvice. But (1) that's just what stopped me; maybe it needs further features (Oreo doesn't implement all of java 8); (2) a completely different approach is to install the java 8 JVM, and not use android's at all. I think there's a 3rd party repository for termux with it (and there *is* a 3rd party arch linux on termux, using `proot`, which might allow it), but I haven't tried either. Pls let me know if you get it working!

Comment: @hyperpallium someone compiled OpenJDK 9 for Termux here: https://archive.org/download/openjdk-9-jre-headless_9.2017.8.20-1_x86_64

Both the JRE and JDK are available, and despite what the URL says, it's available for several architectures, not just x86_64.